# Cordova build path failure in netbeans and node.js

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, netbeans, path

I'm having an error that I can't find a solution for.  I'm trying to get the Android emulator to work with a Cordova application in Netbeans 8.0.  I get this error:

```
Creating android project...
Running command: C:\Users\SS&S\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaMapsSample\platforms\android com.coolappz.CordovaMapsSample CordovaMapsSample
'C:\Users\SS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have git, node.js, and cordova installed in their most recent versions, confirmed via the command prompt.  I have checked my path in my environment variables for the Android Dev tools, and I've tried two versions of that path variable defined with and without escaping the ampersand with a caret (^).  The issue shows up either way.

I still think the error is related to the ampersand, but I'm out of things that I know about to change.

Edit one:  I've already modified the build path under environment variables.  My problem persists.  This is what I have:

`%Path%;%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;C:\Users\SS^&S\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\SS^&S\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: find path(on windows) computer->system property ->advance system setting ->advance - >environment variable

Comment: This is what I have: `%Path%;%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;C:\Users\SS&S\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\SS&S\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Which operates correctly for the Android SDK and the emulator...but not the cordova build.

Comment: also install JRE and then add the JRE's path

Comment: It was the ampersand.  I got it to load by creating a different user and launching from there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a different user without ampersand in name.